# Instatiate a List of <T> , when T is defined as a variable "Class t"

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm trying to write a SyncAdapter that makes a set of requests based on an array of "entities" I made for the purpose.

For this, I have made a small class, that holds the information needed to create the Request, called EntityContract

```
public class EntityContract {

public final SyncContract syncContract;
public final String entityName;
public final String endpoint;
public final Class<? extends ModelClass> modelClass;

public EntityContract(SyncContract syncContract, String entityName, String endpoint , Class<? extends ModelClass> modelClass)
{
    this.syncContract = syncContract;
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
    this.entityName = entityName;
    this.modelClass = modelClass;
}

public String getUrl()
{
    return SyncContract.SERVICE_URL + "/" + endpoint;
}
```

}

In my SyncAdapter I simply iterate over an array of entityContracts to start the request one after another.

The problem I have is, when I try to parse the Response using Gson.
(Thus this is not a Gson related question, I guess. It's about Java semantics)

The gson expects a call in the following structure

```
List< ExampleModel > list = new Gson().fromJson( response.body().charStream() , new TypeToken<List<ExampleModel>>(){}.getType() );
```

or

```
ExampleModel[] list = new Gson().fromJson( response.body().charStream() , ExampleModel[] );
```

where "ExampleModel" had to be replaced with the Class from the entityContract, so it would read something like this:

```
List< myContract.modelClass > list = new Gson().fromJson( response.body().charStream() , new TypeToken<List<myContract.modelClass>>(){}.getType() ); // Won't compile!!!
```

Is it possible to instantiate the List with a parameter read from a Class-variable?
If not, is there another structure to achieve this?

Comment: How are you building an instance of `EntityContract` now?  What gets supplied as the `Class` parameter?

Comment: Why not `List<ModelClass>`?

Comment: there is an overload that takes a class, ModelClass model = new Gson().fromJson("json", modelClass);

Comment: @SleimanJneidi They want a `List` of that.

Comment: @Makoto like this: new EntityContract( mySyncontract , entityName , endpoint , ExampleModel.class )

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom This doesn't work because of the second part of the equation. The gson.fromJson call expects me to provide a concrete class, it can use to factor instances from. Simply passing in the superclass won't do.